# Form tag automatically removed from HTML

Tags: html, css

I have a simple form which includes two input elements.

```
<form class="submitform">   
    <input class="remove_list_items clear_button" type="button" value="A"/>
    <input id="logIn_submit" class="clear_button" type="button"  value="B" />
</form>
```

I see the form written in the source code.
HOWEVER when I inspect the input elements (right click > inspect element / F12) the form tag simply disappears (I can also tell by the fact the input elements are 100% instead of being reduced in width by the form (via css).
What is strange is that if I COPY the form code FROM the source code (CTRL+U), edit the code via inspect element (F12) and replace the code, everything is as it should be.

Code in source code (which is working if I edit via inspect element):

```
<form class="submitform">   
    <input class="remove_list_items clear_button" type="button" value="A"/>
    <input id="logIn_submit" class="clear_button" type="button"  value="B" />
</form>
```

Code that I see via Inspect Element when the page loads (note the FORM tags are missing):

```
<input class="remove_list_items clear_button" type="button" value="A"/>
<input id="logIn_submit" class="clear_button" type="button"  value="B" />
```

This is happening both in Chrome and In IE 10.
I have other forms on the page that display correctly.
Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a jsFiddle.net example?

Comment: Can you reproduce this on a live demo site, such as [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? Because that shouldn't happen for any reason, assuming your HTML is valid, incidentally, have you tried adding `actoion` and `method` attributes to the `form` element?

Comment: Do you have another open form tag further up in the code?

Comment: Hi everyone. Here's the JSFiddle (copied line by line from original code): http://jsfiddle.net/6ZyWU/1/  This is of course NOT happening on JSFiddle. Here's a snapshot from my Chrome inspect element: http://screencast.com/t/sBLrcSDTP5Ml and here's the same element, just from view source: http://screencast.com/t/sBLrcSDTP5Ml

Comment: @Jrod, thank you. That was it, for some reason a previous form closing tag got it's / removed. Thank you. Add as answer and i'll mark it as one. Thank you everyone

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Remove any extra open form tags that haven't been closed.

Chrome will try to fix invalid HTML and doesn't always get it right.

Comment: If you aren't sure, use view-source in Chrome (or an equivalent in other browsers) to get the raw html given to the browser. Then run that through an HTML validator [like this one](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) and then you should be able to find any malformed HTML.

Comment: It might be a bit hacky, but I had the same problem working on an ASP.net webform without control over the wrapping form, I noticed it only removes the first nested form it finds, i added an empty <form></form> above the disappearing one, and that did the trick (my nested form stayed intact)

Comment: Thank you a hundred times! Saved me from wasting an evening!

Comment: That is simply, hands down incredible! Got me unstuck from hours wastage! Thanks!

Comment: Happened to me when I had a form within a form and didn't realize it.  Chrome removed the internal form element.

Comment: @webkit bro it worked for me thank you but it seems down and dirty. ;)

Comment: Thank you so much! Though this looks like a hack, it saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having this issue:

For me the issue was that I had a `form` element as child of another `form`. According to the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form)' permitted content section of the `form` tag, this is invalid HTML. Adding a `form` as child of a `form` causes your browser to remove the invalid HTML, just like [Jared](https://stackoverflow.com/users/745505/jared) mentions.

If I'm not mistaken, this is also what [webkit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1806030/webkit) is saying, although I would not recommend webkit's solution as it's invalid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

There is form in a form probably. Remove the form outside the other form tag.

[image: Click to this picture]

That was the problem for me and I fixed it in this way.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34118806)